# parse inFile line by line while using regex to execute function

Tags: c++, regex, iterator, ifstream, ofstream

I sort of painted myself in a corner and need some guidance. I'm doing some parsing using regex while reading from an infstream. What I want to do is

```
while(getLine(inFile, str)) {

     search(str) for regex match
     if(match)
         str = my_function(str)
         outFile << str
     else 
         outFile unchanged str
}
```

As it stands, I'm doing this:

```
while(getLine(inFile, str)) {

 auto des = std::sregex_iterator(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), dest);
 auto reg_it = std::sregex_iterator();

 std::for_each(des , reg_it, [](std::smatch const& m){
          str = my_function(str)
          outFile << str
        });
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't let me edit the file and write it back out **in order**, as the way I'm doing it only gives me access to the returned matches.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From what you have written, it seems like there may be multiple matches per line, and you want to perform your `my_function()` operation on the string for each such match.  Is that correct?  If so, while not particularly elegant, you could have an `int count = 0;` outside the `for_each()` loop, increment it inside the loop, and check it after the loop.  If it's still 0, just go ahead and do `outFile << str`.

Comment: 1 match per line. So inside of the for_each() loop, I don't have access to any bit of str except those that returned a match.

Comment: Either way, the suggestion I made should still work.  `count` should just never exceed 1.

Comment: I'm trying this: if(std::regex_match(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), matches, myregex)) but can't get it to go.

Comment: There is a description here of how [std::regex_replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) works (using iterators). You may be able to use that algorithm for your problem except instead of calling `m.format()` call your function.

Comment: Your `std::smatch` object doesn't just contain the match, it also contans the text before and after the match: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results see `prefix()` and `suffix()`

Comment: wouldn't I have to iterate back 1 and forward again to get the line before a match? show me how'd you'd implement that, but seems like a pain.

Comment: @Galik I already changed it to the few lines below and it works.

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin My mistake I was looking at your aswer not his, I didn't realize you answered your own question :)

Comment: Haha ya, tbh the real issue was that I had tried it and it worked, but then there was another issue of little carriage returns hiding in my input that was causing nothing to match and so my outFile was empty. I discovered them simultaneously, thank god.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
if (std::regex_match(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), matches , my_regex)) {
        string baz;
        baz = my_function(str); // we have a match
        outFile baz;
}
else outFile << str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
while(getLine(inFile, str)) {

    auto des = std::sregex_iterator(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), dest);
    auto reg_it = std::sregex_iterator();
    int matches = 0;

    std::for_each(des , reg_it, [](std::smatch const& m)){
        str = my_function(str);
        outFile << str;
        matches++;
    });

    if (matches == 0) {
        outFile << str;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems viable now that i've figured it out, but I don't have time to check. I'll try to at some point and give you credit if that's the case. If you're fishing for some, though, you can find me a way to put all of your solution into a function outside of main(), because I've called it half-a-dozen times out of pure laziness.